# Subaru Outback Eyesight failed after just 4 years

Tags: subaru, outback

I have a 2019 Subaru Outback that I bought new.  It's had electrical issues since I bought it.  I took it to the shop 2 to 3 times for Subaru to fix them - e.g. The passenger window button doesn't work from the driver side, issues with the car + phone USB connectivity, echos when talking on the phone, and more.  Finally we've noticed that the Eyesight is glitchy, like saying its unavailable for no good reason. We took the car to the Subaru store. The Subaru Shop said based on the error codes from the eyesight, that they need to replace the entire overhead assembly, new windshield, and possibly something else all to the tune of $5K. They said one camera was showing error codes when they evaluated it. They also mentioned some reasons which made no sense - like

- It was affected by dirt - the window is clean
- There is a toll pass electronic thing stuck on the window causing affecting it - it's been there for years before the eyesight issues began
- There is a crack on the winshield - there is a small rock chip far away from the eyesight, and the eyesight issues began before the rock chip.

Furthermore, It's no longer under warranty they said.

We've taken good care of the car, it seems like they sold us a dud and the staff is perhaps incompetent.

I'm going to get a 2nd opinion, but I was curious if other people have had this type of problem, and how did they resolve it?

I know I was vague in the description of the problem, but if you want more clarification, I'll do my best.

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you have a load of electrical glitches, your eyesight and all other issues could be attributable to a single problem. In any case, as the car isn't under warranty anymore you have no reason to take it to a dealership, take it to an independent mechanic with a good reputation for an evaluation. Dealerships have an often  well-deserved bad reputation for ripping people off, $5000 is exorbitant for your problem. You may want to look at your area's lemon laws as well.

Comment: Now you know why we're reluctant to lend-lease the Abrams, F-16 and other advanced stuff to Ukraine. "It's the hydrazine", the huge radar, threat alerters and countermeasures, and other things that make them awesome, also make them expensive to maintain in good working order. And without them, not so awesome.   I am not surprised creature-comfort and autopilot features like these are the first to go, given how spectacularly reliable engines and transmissions are in this day and age.

Comment: yes, it's exactly the same problem as I have with my Subaru.

Anyways, the guy in the shop winked and said that there were finger prints on the camera lens, and they're advised not to clean them. I can do it myself....  We shall see what happens.